# TimeShift + Ubuntu 16.04 is stable?

Tags: 16.04, backup

I would like to know if someone use with success TimeShift with Ubuntu 16.04 as I don't find anything about, even the official website of this app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this tutorials seem work fine: http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/30/create-system-restore-points-ubuntu-16-04/ and https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/timeshift.html

Officil github repo: https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift

I was able also to install and make first snapshot with success.

I just get an message after trying to browse files of snapshot created, that need to create folder /root/.config/nautilus or give permission for create. But only one time appear.

Comment: If you don't have enough free space on disk, you may end up with `no disk space`, because it starts to back up immediately when you exit the `GUI`. I found the backup location in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/timeshift/`

Comment: I am doing backup on external usb drive.

Answer (score 2):

It works very well.
Tested timeshift with rsync before, but quickly converted my partitions to btrfs.
Still using rsync for backups to external hdd or cloning laptops at work (but acronis does the job faster).

I use it with BTRFS on my private and work laptop and also on some dev systems. 
Systems with a broken config, strange sys behaviour or broken updates can be repaired by executing a simple rollback. Which is around 10 times faster with BTRFS compared to an rsync source (only takes as long as a reboot).

RSYNC has to copy a lot of files back to the system and either needs a working network connection or a connected backup drive.
BTRFS (simplified) sees the file system as volume layers, consisting of snapshots. Each one is an incremental volume of the partition.
For a rollback, it mounts the the chosen snapshot as tha current main volume and also retains the snapshot from before the rollback, so newer files can be found and restored by using a diff between those 2 virtual volumes (diff backup|old state).

We often (intentionally) break the dev system software. Rollback to snapshot, and it works all fine again.

Also on production servers. If updates go wrong or other serious errors happen, I create a snapshot and roll back the system to the snapshot before that update.
After the system is up and running again, log files can be extracted from the "pre rollback" snapshot.

Very useful tool to ensure system availability with reliable rollbacks.
Also works fine on ubuntu 18.04 and mint 19 (which includes snapshots by default before updating)